# Is there a pen and paper rpg adaptation of Half Life?

Tags: game-recommendation

Just out of curiosity: Do you know of a good (un)official **pen and paper rpg adaptation of** the famous first person shooter computer game series **Half Life**?

I know there are games/systems in which a crafty GM (with a lot of spare time on their hands :)) could recreate the world of Half Life out of scratch, but/so please don't list such unless they have specific, official or unofficial HL "expansions".

(Yes, this question was inspired by the recent release of [Beyond Black Mesa](http://beyondblackmesa.com/), a short fan movie for HL2. Disclaimer: I'm in no way related to said movie.)

Comment: I think this is a great question! Although personally I would be more interested in HL2 as a setting.

Comment: Thanks. :) HL2 is what I'm primarily interested in, just like you, but HL1 would also be better than nothing - that's why I tried to word the question to include the whole series. Thanks again!

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't actually read or run either of these, but there's a [Savage Worlds conversion of HL](http://mysticbull.pbworks.com/w/page/21997846/halflife) and a [d20 Modern partially-finished conversion of HL2](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Half-Life_%28D20_Modern_Campaign_Setting%29).

Comment: I had to remove my upvote based on my evolved understanding of the system recommendation rules (see @BBS's comment on the question). I didn't go so far as to downvote, but since this answer doesn't reference actual experience, I had to remove the upvote.

Comment: I didn't realize we had system recommendation rules. WHY WAS I NOT INFORMED?! :)

Comment: Oh, I see, it's a recent development. I like it. Per the recommendation, you're totally within your rights to downvote (viciously), but I appreciate that you didn't since I wasn't actually breaking protocol when I wrote this answer.

To be fair, the OP asks if anyone knows of a system, not if anyone has experience with a system. Perhaps an unintended consequence of our sys-rec policy is that little used resources will tend to remain obscure, while widely-used resources will tend to remain well-known. So we may end up inadvertently promoting inferior resources with good marketing.

Comment: I hate it when I get downvoted without an explanation of why - how am I supposed to improve my answer that way? So I thought I owed you the same courtesy I would want. I don't think your answer is bad or without value, it just doesn't meet our standards. I know it's an answer older than the guidelines, but part of what makes SE work so well is the drive for constant improvement. You'll note I don't think I have a **better** answer than this!

Comment: I agree completely. I do really appreciate the feedback. Hope I didn't come off as complaining.

Comment: Nope! Not at all.

Answer (score 4):

It's not very polished, but there's a [d20 Modern adaptation of Half-Life 2](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19877986/Half_Life_D20%3a_Welcome_to_City_17) as a rough series of posts on the Wizards forums.

Comment: Hey, @mxy want to revise this in terms of our sys-rec pro-forma?

Comment: What, by deleting it?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using your favorite modern-era game, armed with your love of the HL2 setting and this book: [*Half-Life 2: Raising the Bar* by David Hodgson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0761543643).

Comment: even though this is not the kind of answer I asked for in the question (no specific rpg adaptation), I'm very, very tempted to accept it solely for bringing that book to my attention. (I'll have to buy it some day, hopefully soon.) ...but that would be unfair towards the others who answered. :-o anyway, thanks a real lot!

Comment: Of course! Use the book in combination with one of cr0m's recommendations for best results ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am [currently writing a Half Life RPG](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1On_72SEtKTMGePNrSBXtPUezprlgoM8b9xL5P7EiuqQ/edit), I'm sort of basing it off of the [Fallout Pen and Paper RPG](http://falloutpnp.wikia.com) that I'm playing with some friends. The game I'm writing is both HL2 and the first one.

Comment: I was hoping that you would link to your original work…

Comment: Any progress updates on your writing?

Comment: I'm almost finished with actual writing. I still have to fill in the brainstorms that I left there. Aesthetics and pictures still have to happen too. Please look at it, and give me some feedback. Thanks.